# Access older revision of SVN repo via HTTP / mod_svn

Tags: apache, svn

Using the mod_svn module for apache you can access the repository not onl via SVN client but also directly via HTTP using the same URL. You only get a plain directory listing showing the HEAD revision in such a case.

**It is possible (may be via URL parameters) to access older revisions of the SVN repository if they has net been copied/tagged within the SVN?**

I know that there are 3rd party software that allows to do so like ViewCV or WebSVN but I am interested in how far you get with only a plain SVN repository accessible via mod_svn and HTTP(S).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `r` querystring parameter to access older versions of files and directory listings with mod_dav_svn. For example:

```
http://host.example.com/repos/project/trunk/README.txt?r=1234
```

The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing) has more details on how this works.

Comment: In case anybody else wonders since when this is supported: It was introduced in version 1.6 of Subversion.