# Is ther an http-argument for svn-history via http(s) GET?

Tags: svn

i was wondering if you could access the svn-commit-history via http/https, something like

[Access older revision of SVN repo via HTTP / mod_svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897221/access-older-revision-of-svn-repo-via-http-mod-svn)

for revisions? i am using svn version 1.6.17.

Comment: The question you link says *HTTP* but means *web browser* (Subversion clients use HTTP as well). Do you also mean that?

Comment: yes. i edited my question (added " GET") to contribute for that (it should be accessible via web browser, i want to be able to bookmark the link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The web browsing view built into SVN is very minimal. If you need something more full-featured, install a repository browser application on your server like [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) to interface with the repository.